# What is maximum decimal precision in Marklogic 10 and How to use in my json document?

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-9

I'm trying to insert a JSON document with decimal props which is having more than 10 decimal precision, but it auto applying rounding to 9 and when I get that document it is showing only 9 decimal precision.

```
declareUpdate(); 
var uri = '/test.json'; 
var root = { id: 1, value: 56900.123456789012345678901 }; 
xdmp.documentInsert(uri, root);
```

Any idea to insert/get more than 9 decimal precision in MarkLogic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In JSON numbers are double precision.

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7159

> Since software that implements    IEEE 754-2008 binary64 (double
> precision) numbers [IEEE754] is    generally available and widely
> used, good interoperability can be    achieved by implementations that
> expect no more precision or range    than these provide, in the sense
> that implementations will    approximate JSON numbers within the
> expected precision.  A JSON    number such as 1E400 or
> 3.141592653589793238462643383279 may indicate    potential interoperability problems, since it suggests that the    software that
> created it expects receiving software to have greater    capabilities
> for numeric magnitude and precision than is widely    available.

So, you will get up to 17 significant digits.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format

> The 53-bit significand precision gives from 15 to 17 significant
> decimal digits precision (2−53 ≈ 1.11 × 10−16). If a decimal string
> with at most 15 significant digits is converted to IEEE 754
> double-precision representation, and then converted back to a decimal
> string with the same number of digits, the final result should match
> the original string. If an IEEE 754 double-precision number is
> converted to a decimal string with at least 17 significant digits, and
> then converted back to double-precision representation, the final
> result must match the original number.[1]

You will get the same result if you execute the following in the browsers console:

```
56900.123456789012345678901 + 0
```

It returns

```
56900.12345678901
```

And if you move the decimal to the right, same number of significant digits:

```
5690012345678901.2345678901 + 0
```

yields:

```
5690012345678901
```

You could store the value as a string, in order to retain the full precision, but will likely lose it if converting to any of the supported numeric types.

What do you need that level of precision for?

Comment: We are migrating database from oracle to marklogic. In oracle we have many decimal fields with more than 20 precision. So I'm trying to find the better solution to migrate exact data from oracle to ML. Anyway you provided good overview of JSON.

Comment: More info on MarkLogic’s numeric precision is available at https://help.marklogic.com/Knowledgebase/Article/View/487. If you just need storage and not math computation, you could make the value a JSON or XML string value.

Comment: So far I'm not doing any calculation in javascript ML modules. I will try to convert decimal to string and store it to Marklogic. Thanks all.